# adding filter search inside of a form so it can post data

Tags: javascript, ruby, html

I am currently learning ruby and am trying to add a filter/search bar like this one https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp. Inside of a form. so in theory I could get one of the params from the filter search and other params from user input.

```
<h1>Add a new coin to your Coinfolio</h1>
<form id = "post-form" method = "post" action = "/coins">


<input type="text" id="coin-search-bar" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for coins..">

<ul id="available-coin-list">
  <% @available_coins.each_with_index do |coin, index| %>
  <li>
    <a>
      <%= coin.name %>  price = $ <%= coin.current_price  %>
      <input type = "text" name = "price_paid" placeholder="price paid:"/>
      <input type = "hidden" name = "coin_id" value = "<%= coin.id %>">
      <input type = "submit">
    </a>
  </li>

  <% end %>
</ul>
</form>
```

this is what I have so far however im not getting any values in the params hash who clicking submit. also would rather be able to have only one search button and input field. Any ideas how i can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Im learning too, but this is how I implemented a search bar into my navbar. maybe helps. This code is a partial html.erb that I render into my navbar.html.

```
<div class="advanced_search_container">
<div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
  <%= form_tag(dresses_path, {class: 'search form-inline my-2 my-lg-0', method: 'get'}) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, '', class: " mr-sm-2", placeholder: "Find The Dress" %>
    <%= select_tag :size, options_for_select(Dress::SIZES), :prompt => "size", class: "select", style: "border-bottom:0px solid !important; margin-left:5px;width: 70px;"%>
    <%= select_tag :category, options_for_select(Dress::CATEGORIES), :prompt => "category" , class: "select", style: "border-bottom:0px solid !important; margin-left:5px;width: 70px;" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: " search btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 "%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```